# vuejs split to string to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, ionic-framework

I've got a string that's formatted in a textbox as comma-separated, however when I try and split it convert it to an array to loop through them I'm getting the error

```
Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

My textbox (using ionic, but essentially just a textarea when rendered

```
<ion-textarea type="text" v-model="CSVItems" placeholder="e.g. chicken, rice, peas"></ion-textarea>
```

The data/methods are as follows (cut down to just necessary for the post)

```
 data() {
    return {
      CSVItems: "",
      myResult: "",
    };
  },
  methods: {
     addItem: function() {
      this.myResult = this.CSVItems.split(",");
  },
```

[image]

Comment: `split` returns an array. Looks like vuejs is enforcing the type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is about trying to store an array of strings to a property declared as a string. To inform tslint about the correct type, instantiate `myResult` as an array of strings:

```
data: () => ({
  CSVItems: "",
  myResult: [] as string[]
})
```

Additionally, you might want to also trim before assigning:

```
this.myResult = this.CSVItems.split(',').map(s => s.trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

The javascript [split function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) on a string returns an array. To turn it into a string you can use [Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) to make them a string again

Ex.

```js
let CSVItems = "Hello,World!"

console.log(CSVItems.split(',')
// ["Hello", "World!"]


// Array.join's parameter is what to append with Ex [1,2,3].join("t") = "1t2t3"
console.log(CSVItems.split(',').join(' '))
// "Hello World!"
```

If you want myResult to be an array you have to set it as one

```js
 data() {
    return {
      CSVItems: "",
      myResult: [], // Make [] not ""
    };
  },
  methods: {
     addItem: function() {
      this.myResult = this.CSVItems.split(",");
  },
```